# How can I import GoPro mp4 video to iMovie 11?

Tags: video, imovie, encoding

I have video in an MP4 file from a GoPro camera.  It imports fine into iMovie on my iPad Mini and I can edit it there, but I'd rather edit in iMovie 11 on my Mac (OSX 10.9).  However, iMovie 11 won't import the GoPro MP4 video files.

They play fine on Quicktime Player on the Mac, but iMovie refuses to import them.  Quicktime says the MP4 files contain "GoPro AVC encoder, 1280x720 AAC, 48000 Hz stereo, 29.97 FPS".

Why does iPad iMovie work but not the iMovie 11?  Do I have to get a converter to convert to a different encoding?  If so, which encoding?

Answer (score 1):

This problem solved itself when I upgraded to the final OS 10.9 (Mavericks) and installed the latest iMovie.  Now I can import MP4 files from the GoPro right into iMovie.